# Why has the ANSI 3.64 standard been withdrawn?

Tags: terminal, history, standard

From the [Wikipedia "ANSI escape code"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#History) article:

> The name "ANSI escape sequence" dates from 1981 when ANSI adopted ECMA-48 as the standard ANSI X3.64 (and later, in 1997, withdrew it).

Does anybody know why the standard has been withdrawn. I tried to follow the link in the article but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this paragraph in a withdrawal letter for [FIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standards) which might be why it was withdrawn:

*excerpt from [withdrawal letter](http://www.nist.gov/itl/upload/Withdrawn-FIPS-by-Numerical-Order-Index.pdf)*

> It is no longer necessary for the government to mandate standards
>   that duplicate  industry standards. Federal government departments and
>   agencies are directed by  the National Technology Transfer and
>   Advancement Act of 1995 (P.L. 104-113),  to use technical industry
>   standards that are developed in voluntary consensus  standards bodies.

There is also this letter/email:

```
 From: "richard l. hogan"
 <Richard=L.=Hogan%dpi%hqnmd@mcmcban6.er.usgs.gov>  Date: Tue, 29 Oct
 96 9:20:26 CST  Subject: Withdrawal of FIPS
```

Which discusses that the NIST and the Dept. of Commerce were dropping national designations for things such as ANSI 3.64 when they already had a international designation (ISO).

*excerpt from that [letter/email](http://py-iso8211.sourceforge.net/tibbs/FIPS.html)*

> One of the pieces of legislation that, according to NIST and the
>   Department of Commerce, enabled the FIPS program was rescinded this
>   year. The law - sometimes referred to as the Brooks Act - contained
>   specific requirements for establishing uniform standards for
>   information processing in the Federal government and for making those
>   standards mandatory in Federal procurement actions. OMB Circular A-119
>   further clarified that mandatory Federal standards took precedence
>   over voluntary national and international standards. Now, as a result
>   of treaty negotiations making the Untied States part of the World
>   Trade Organization, the Books Act has been replaced with new
>   legislation that requires Federal agencies to consider voluntary
>   international and national standards FIRST in procurement actions and
>   to cite Federal standards only when no appropriate international or
>   national standards exist.
>
> In many cases FIPS have international (ISO) or national (ANSI)
>   standard equivalents. For example, FIPS 123 (Data Descriptive Format
>   for Information Interchange) is also ISO-8211. The change in
>   legislation requires Federal procurements to now cite ISO-8211.
>   Previously, we were required to cite FIPS- 123. As a result of this
>   change, NIST has recognized an opportunity to make government "work
>   better and cost less" by withdrawing any FIPS that already has an
>   equivalent ANSI or ISO specification or any FIPS that is not
>   mandatory; i.e., is just a guideline. What remains on the "active"
>   FIPS list are mandatory Federal standards which currently have no ANSI
>   or ISO equivalent; for example, the Spatial Data Transfer Standard
>   (FIPS 173-1) and the Government Information Locator Service (FIPS
>   192).
>
> NIST is not withdrawing important standards like Pascal, FIPS 109;
>   SGML, FIPS 152; or Hydrologic Unit Codes, FIPS 103. The proper way to
>   look at this action is that NIST is withdrawing the Federal
>   designation of these standards in favor or their national or
>   international standards designations; ANSI X3.97-1993 for FIPS 103,
>   ISO 8879 for FIPS 152, and ANSI X3.145-1986 for FIPS 103. From a user
>   point of view, this action by NIST is nothing more than a way to
>   assure the designation change required by the new legislation.

I would interpret this as follows: Since ECMA-48 already covered the standard at an international level there was no need to create redundant standards within ANSI.

Comment: [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf) is superior to ANSI 3.64 in one regard, section 7.2.1 finally explains what that acronym stands for:  BI-DIRECTIONAL SUPPORT MODE.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone - thanks for the addition!